# How to run this command in os process sampler in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a command something like ssh ***@****. When I execute this command in CMD it asks for password and upon entering the password, the connection will be successful. Please help me how can I handle this using os process sampler

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you cannot handle this using [`ssh` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) as it doesn't allow providing the password as the parameter, it can only open an [interactive shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/What-is-an-Interactive-Shell_003f.html) which is not supported by the OS Process Sampler.

So instead of `ssh` client you need to consider the following alternatives:

1. Use [key-based authentication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server) so you won't have to provide the password
2. Use [`sshpass` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass)
3. Use [`expect` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)
4. Switch to [SSH Command](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command) sampler which allows execution of arbitrary commands over SSH channel, it supports both password and key-based authentication mechanisms, see [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for more details

Comment: Thank you, I will check and get back to you